# How can I create custom Ads in my iPhone app?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iad, ads

I am developing an iPhone app for my University radio station, and I would like to insert ads (that look and feel just like iAds) but with my own custom designs/content/links so I can sell this adspace to possible sponsors.
Would anyone know how I can do this or point me in the right direction? I am building a "utility" style app.

Answer (score 2):

I have a JSON file on my server with certain data about the ad (mine happens to be set up for one, but you could accomodate multiple the same way).

```
{"promo":"yes","imageURL":"http://somedomain/testAd.png","image2xURL":"http://somedomain/testAd@2x.png","link":"http://www.whereTheAdShouldDirect.com"}
```

Then, in the app, I have this amongst the rest of viewWillAppear:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain/promo.php"];

NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
const char *convert = [response UTF8String];
NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
NSDictionary *promo = [responseString JSONValue];

[response release];
if([[promo objectForKey:@"promo"] isEqualToString:@"yes"]){
    self.linkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[promo objectForKey:@"link"]];
    NSURL *picURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[promo objectForKey:@"imageURL"]];
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]intValue]>=4){
        if([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]==2.0){
            picURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[promo objectForKey:@"image2xURL"]];
        }
    }
    CGRect imgFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
    UIButton *adImage=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:imgFrame];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:picURL];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [adImage setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [adImage addTarget:self action:@selector(ad) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:adImage];
    [adImage release];
}
```

and this method as well:

```
-(void)ad{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:self.linkURL];
}
```

You may want to change that last method depending on how you want the ad to react (load a webview right in the app?)

Comment: Thank you so very much for the answer. 
I am having trouble with the JSON part. How do I put this file on my server? 
Save as .json? or do I put .json file in PhP, then save as .php?

Comment: It depends on how your data is held...if you are pulling from a database (maybe because you have many ads) the i would use php to query the DB, then echo JSON encoded data. If its just one ad that rarely changes, you can have a static text file